Wiring an immersion heater to two possible power supplies
I have a holiday property that has a hot water storage tank, heated using an immersion heater. Currently, the power for the immersion heater is on a timed power supply. There is a button that, when pressed, provides power to the immersion heater for 30 minutes and then turns off (left in the pic). This means that guests can't leave it turned on.
However, I also have an electricity tariff that varies and sometimes very cheap.
What I would like to do is be able to override the timed supply with a direct supply when the tariff is cheap. I have a socket that I can turn on and off using Wifi (right in the pic).
What is the best way to achieve this? Presumably I can't wire them both to the immersion heater directly. I wondered if a relay would do the trick.

For clarity, I do not need advice on the computer side of things. Just consider the two supplies in the diagram as being connected to two individual switches, on the same circuit. How they are turned on and off is not the issue. I am unsure if I can wire them both into the heater or would I need a system to flip between them.
For example a relay. When socket 2 was switched on, the relay would connect the heater to socket 2, but if not, would revert to socket 1.

The word is immersion, not emersion.

Ha - good point

How do you know when power is cheap, i.e. what is the thing that is will be controlling the decision to heat the water?

Assuming both outlets are on the same circuit, then there shouldn’t be an issue - essentially two switches in parallel.

I have written a computer program to manage that. It currently controls all of my floor heating and wall heaters. It gets the current rate every 30 minutes from the provider and the software then sends on/off signals to the devices in the home. Works well.

@Kartman Is that right? What if they happen to both on at the same time? Does that cause a problem/a little dangerous?

So you want to have a computer control a heating element?  Does it need to also monitor the temperature of the water to avoid boiling it?  Put these details in the question.

What about using a Shelly switch? (not affiliated). The "guest button" would send a request to your home automation. And your software would control the Shelly; power ON on demand for 30 minutes; or continuously ON during low tariff.

@RGriffiths as I said - effectively two switches in parallel. Both can be on.  I’m with LordTeddy with using a WiFi switch - you can purchase units with open source firmware like Tasmota that you can script to do just about anything you want.

@Velvet Thanks - I have not come across Shelly switches but presume they do the same as my WiFi socket (if I bought a WiFi switch). The ones I buy connect to the api I use.

I just mentioned some random WiFi switch with an API (well not entirely random - it's one I've used). I'm sure there are many others that work just as fine.

I'd perhaps be inclined not to touch the mains wiring, even if there's no risk. It's the sort of thing an insurance company would use as an excuse not to pay out. 
But you could just have the same appliance wired to two plugs. If both plugs are on at the same time, no additional connection is being made.That being said, I would want to ensure the two plugs are socket/outlet. If you use two different outlets, that are physically close to each other, but because of how the house is wired are actually some distance apart electrically, then there is the possibility that the wiring for this might offer a shorter path and cause problems. Or if there's an electrical fault where a wire fails open, you could find that a lot of current flows through your dual plugs to bypass the failed wire.
EDIT Greybeard also points out a significant risk, whereby when one plug is plugged in, the second will also be energized. Particularly in a house available for guests, that's a big deal.
It sounds like you're happy writing a bit of software, so it seems to me like a better way would be to use an Internet of Things button that the guest can press to end up turning the wifi switch on for 30 minutes.

I Presume you mean safety risk, not security. Can you articulate why?

(I think I could put the risk in words.)

Assuming both plugs connected permanently, there is the risk of touching the prongs of the one not plugged in. When plugging the second one, you can hope polarities/phases match.They don't, you can hope the CB prevents damage up to starting a fire.

@LordTeddy Thanks - that would work, and easy enough to set up 'IoT'wise, but I am still interested in the two switch solution. I have bought a 240v relay to switch to the WiFi socket when the WiFi socket is active, and flip back to the timer when it isn't. Testing it off site at the moment.
